# Send data from android device to java card error

Tags: android, javacard, nexus-s, apdu

I am new to Android NFC development.I have created android application which using ISOdep send data to java card.In my java card applet i get data from APDU command and encrypted data using RSA2048 and send back to Android application.So I am using NEXUS S and Jcop 81 card for the testing.My problem is when i remove the java card while processing encryption the Android device(nexus s) gives wired sound.After that i try to tap again then always it gives this wired sound.And then I reset java card using JCOP tools and tap again.now it works fine.In here [How to Reset java card using APDU command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340842/how-to-reset-java-card-using-apdu-command/18351391?noredirect=1#18351391)  i asked how to reset java card before we selecting applet.But android or java card API doesn't support for the RESET.How can i solve this problem.Is there are any way like begin transaction and endtransaction like in javax.smartcardio Or Is there any other  way to do this process??Other thing i want to know is this problem common for all android devices?
Sajith

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "reset Java Card using JCOP tools"? What exact steps do you take? PS. I do program JCOP shell myself.

Comment: Thanks Owlsted. It is happy to get advice from you. Reset means I send /atr command and then i thought it was resetting .the reason is After doing that i can send data back to the java card.

Comment: If you are up to it, I found [this](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2511437) a very interesting read.

Comment: Thanks owlstead.if yopu ok can you tell me /atr command which we send using Jcop shell is APDU command??

Comment: It certainly is not an APDU command. As stipulated before, there is no such thing as a APDU `RESET` command. The reason being that APDU's are higher level (Application Protocol Data Unit). A reset is not part of the application protocol.

Comment: @Sajith4U, can you provide some more context? The weird sound sounds like your device is receiving a new NFC intent which is not handled. Are you enabling foreground dispatch for the particular activity that is calling `ISODep.tranceive`? How are you handling `IOException`s? Did you set a timeout on `ISODep`?